# Custom range-based iterator for a templated vector of vectors

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I have an assignment that's been driving me insane. I've been researching basic concepts to increase my knowledge and try to apply it to this problem but I'm a bit stuck.

We have a main.cpp file that tests a VectorOfVectors class that has this syntax:

```
for( int num : intVov )
{
     printf( "%d ", num );
}
```

We're creating our own VectorOfVectors class with templated vectors as items.

We have to make the main function properly work by creating our own custom iterator that iterates through all the values, as shown by the main function. I've been researching range-based iterators but I'm a little confused as to how to construct my own, and because it is a vector of vectors the syntax does not match well with some online examples.

I would like guidance as to how I can go about creating this iterator. I know I need a begin() and end() function, as well as override the operator++ function to get it to work. Would my iterator use int values as the pointer(s) that I increment in operator++? Would I need two pointers? What would begin() and end() return, iterators, or integers, or T values, or vectors? How should I construct the iterator and what data do I need for it? Would the iterator constructor take two pointers as values, or one, or how would that work? Would the iterator need its own copy of a VectorOfVectors to iterate (and be set in a constructor)?

How would I go about increasing the pointers? Any help, general knowledge or even tips would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've been fiddling around, just as a reference.

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;


template< typename T > class VectorOfVectors
{
public:

    class iterator
    {
        public:
            //Constructor
            iterator(const VectorOfVectors<T> * vov, int pos_vov, int pos_v)
            {
                _pos_vov = pos_vov;
                _pos_v = pos_v;
                _vov = vov;
            }

            bool operator!= (const iterator & other) const
            {
                return pos != other._pos;
            }

            int operator* () const;

            const iterator operator++ ()
            {
                _pos_v++;
                if (_pos_v == _pos_vov->end())
                {
                    _pos_vov++;
                    if (_pos_vov == _vov.end())
                    {
                        --_pos_vov;
                        _pos_v = _pos_vov->end();
                        --_pos_v;
                        return (*this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _pos_v = _pos_vov->begin();
                        return (*this);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return (*this);
                }
            }

    private:
        int _pos_v;
        int _pos_vov;
        const VectorOfVectors<T> * _vov;
    };

    void AddEmptyVector()
    {
        vectorOfVectors.push_back(new vector<T>());
    }

    int GetVectorCount() const
    {
        return vectorOfVectors.size();
    }

    vector<T> GetVectorAtIndex(int index)
    {
        return vectorOfVectors.at(index);
    }

    void AddCopyOfVector(vector<T> & toBeAdded)
    {
        vectorOfVectors.push_back(toBeAdded);
    }

    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iter(this, 0, 0);
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(this, 4, 3);
    }

private:
    vector< vector<T> > vectorOfVectors = new vector< vector<T> >();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `for` loop that you posted, it seems that the instructor wants the iterator to iterate over individual elements of the vector-of-vectors (rather than, for instance, over the sub-vectors).

`begin()` and `end()` must always return *iterators*, not the elements pointed to by iterators (so e.g. not raw `int`s in this case).  In certain special cases it might be possible to make these raw pointers (for example I think certain STL implementations of `std::vector::iterator` do this), but generally they will need to be small `struct`s containing enough information to navigate the parent data structure.

See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for a good description of what the `for (var : collection)` syntax actually translates to.  This tells you that you need to design an iterator type `Iter` that has the following properties:

- `*Iter` returns a `T`, or something convertible to `T` (like `T&`).  You currently have this wrong -- your `int operator* () const;` (which doesn't appear to be defined?) is returning an `int`, for some reason.
- `++Iter` moves the iterator to the next element.
- `Iter1 != Iter2` returns `false` when the two iterators are pointing at the same element.

How you actually create the `Iter` type is completely up to you.  Using 2 integer indices and checking for "wraparound" on `++` as you're currently doing seems sound to me.

Other notes:

- Your `begin()` currently calls `return iter(this, 0, 0);`, which won't even compile.
- Please don't dynamically allocate pointers to `std::vector`, as you do in the declaration of `vectorOfVectors` and in `AddEmptyVector()`.  For a start, neither will compile, because for them to compile you would need to declare `vectorOfVectors` as a *pointer to* a vector of *pointers to* vectors, and you don't want to do that, because `std::vector` manages its own dynamic memory allocation internally -- avoid having to ever call `new` and `delete` is the main reason you use a `std::vector` in the first place.

Comment: You are god-sent and I appreciate your suggestions. I will look into this further. Thank you for your reply.